# How to save the path of the SQLite image and then retrieve it?

Tags: android, sql

I have this class that captures the image and then saves it in SQLite, but from what I understand, it saves as blob, (I found this code on the internet and reused a part), I wanted to actually save the path and then retrieve it, because the way it is the quality drops a lot.

```
public class fotos extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    static final int CAPTURE_PHOTO = 2;

    private FloatingActionButton add;
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    private int progressBarStatus = 0;
    private Handler progressBarHandler = new Handler();
    DbHelper dbHelper;

    boolean active = false;

    Bitmap thumbnail;

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    ImagesAdapter imagesAdapter;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private static final int IMAGES_LOADER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotos);

        add = findViewById(R.id.add);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        imagesAdapter = new ImagesAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(imagesAdapter);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(IMAGES_LOADER, null, this);

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fotos.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(fotos.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }else{
           active = true;
        }

        dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent it = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(it, CAPTURE_PHOTO);
    }

    public void setProgressBar(){
        progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressBar.setCancelable(true);
        progressBar.setMessage("Espera, por favor...");
        progressBar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.show();
        progressBarStatus = 0;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(progressBarStatus < 100){
                    progressBarStatus += 30;

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    progressBarHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progressBarStatus);
                        }
                    });
                }
                if(progressBarStatus >= 100){
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == CAPTURE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        //thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        setProgressBar();
        thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] date = baos.toByteArray();
        dbHelper.addToDb(date);
        Toast.makeText(fotos.this, "Imagem salva com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        String[] projetion = {
                DbHelper.COLUMN_NAME,
        };

        return new CursorLoader(this,
                ImagesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                projetion,
                null,
                null,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        imagesAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        imagesAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
}
```

Db:

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String TAG = DbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "image.db";
    private static final int DATABAS_VERSION = 1;
    Context context;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ContentResolver mContentResolver;

    public final static String COLUMN_NAME = "imagename";
    public final static String TABLE_NAME = "imagetable";


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABAS_VERSION);

        mContentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        final String SQL_CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME + " BLOB NOT NULL " + " );";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_IMAGE_TABLE);
        Log.d(TAG, "Database criado com sucesso!");
    }

    public void addToDb(byte[] date) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, date);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
 <application>
  ...
 <activity android:name=".activitys.info_sinistro.midia.fotos" >
            <meta-data
                android:name=".activitys.info_sinistro.midia.fotos"
                android:value=".activitys.info_sinistro.midia.fotos"/>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name=".activitys.info_sinistro.Provider.ImagesProvider"
            android:authorities="insidetechnology.studio.ostdor.xiope"
            android:exported="true"/>
      ...
      </application>
```

In API 24 I know you need this provider, so that would be correct?

Comment: What is a typical size of images you are going to put in `SQLite` DB? If megabytes, it is not a good idea to do that. You have to use some image  loader ([Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for example) with settings forcing `Glide` to keep images on it's disk cache.

Comment: After some time these images will be deleted, I even need to save the path to load with the recyclerView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the same principle in my app, I'm using a built-in camera to capture an image and save the path to it in a database.
Basically, once you click the camera button you dispatch an intent, which you know already, but I will share it for completeness:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while creating the file");
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mFile = photoFile;
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.yourpackage.fileprovider", photoFile);
            //Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that in order for the `FileProvider` to work you need to include this in your manifest file inside `<application>` tag:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.yourpackage.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
        </meta-data>
    </provider>
```

And `@xml/file_paths`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="my_images" path="." />
</paths>
```

And finally in your `dispatchTakePictureIntent()` you also create a file using `createImageFile()` :

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    File path = new File(Util.getFileDirectory(getActivity()), "FOLDER_NAME");
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "FileName_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";

    if(path.mkdirs()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Directory created");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Directory is already present");
    }

    return new File(path, imageFileName);
}
```

And finally, you get the image in `onActivityResult()` :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // you got the photo
            String imagePath = mImage.getAbsolutePath() 
            // you can save this path to the database
        } else if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while taking a photo. Error " + resultCode);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work, but maybe there are some extra unneeded steps with the `FileProvider`, please someone correct me if I am wrong. But this code is working.

Comment: Dude, make my sister pregnant.

Comment: @Bestfastfire best comment ever haha, made my day, glad I could help :)

Comment: Whats is `Util`
in this part `        File path = new File(Util.getFileDirectory(fotos.this), "FOLDER_NAME");` It's giving you that it is not possible to solve a symbol

Comment: My bad, it's just a utility class that I created in order to get the pictures directory, you can replace it with `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` it fetches a directory in external storage that contains pictures. There is also internal storage that is local to your app and is not persisted if you delete your app, you can fetch it with `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. Basically, with the first one pictures will be accessible across the system, and with the second they will be only visible to your app.

Comment: @Bestfastfire perfect, tell me if you have more questions