# how to take picture with custom button

Tags: android

I have opened camera in my application now i want to take picture on **button click**. I have created two activities :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Camera mCamera = null;
private CameraView mCameraView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(mCamera != null) {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);
    }

    ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
}

}
```

**CameraActivity which open the camera and starts preview:**

```
public class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;
public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera){
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
    //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try{
        //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i2, int i3) {
    //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
    if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
        return;

    try{
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
    }

    //now, recreate the camera preview
    try{
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
    //if you are unsing with more screens, please move this code your activity
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}}
```

I want to take a picture on `OnClick` method in `MainActivity`. `CameraActivity` opens the camera and start the preview while a button (cross) is to take the picture. I am new in android application development and have no idea how to take picture and then store it in bitmap and show in `ImageView`. further i will process that bitmap. but for now i want to take picture from camera and save it in bitmap and show in `ImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to take a picture and save it, then I believe there is no point in implementing your own Camera and using `SurfaceView`, just use the camera app that is already present on the device, it's much easier. I answered a similar question and provided the code, you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49888419/7915814). But before you look it up, first look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics), it explains really well how to capture an image by delegating the work to another camera app.

And if you still want to implement your own camera, there is a method called `takePicture`, which is called as following `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture)`, where `mPicture` is an instance of `PictureCallback`. Just open the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) and look for the section "Capturing Pictures", you will find an example there.